# How to use spring security with POST from html forms?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a `spring` backend service and want to allow sending `POST` requests from a html `form`.

Problem: I'm always receiving a `403 forbidden` when sending the POST.
BUT: I can successful login into the app. So my authentication configuration should be fine in general.

Maybe I'm missing a detail for my `@PostMapping` controller? Do I have to apply further security annotations on that controller?

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
              .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
              .withUser("test")
              .password("test")
              .authorities(Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }
}
```

My form is just plain simple (included in a `thymeleaf` template):

```html
<form id="edit-form" action="https://localhost:8080/person" method="post">
    <input type="text"...>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

```java
@Controller
public class PersonController {
    @PostMapping("/person")
    public String addItem(Person p) {
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

The debug logs show: `FilterSecurityInterceptor: Authorization successful`. Though I'm getting the forbidden:

```
2020-11-26 12:21:54.342 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /filter at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.342 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /filter at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.342 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@442b46a2: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@442b46a2: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@364492: Username: test; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: F21871A713E04DDC161BC4072F553A68; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.342 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /filter at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.342 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /filter at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.342 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.c.CsrfFilter                     : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8070/filter
2020-11-26 12:21:54.343 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.h.w.HstsHeaderWriter             : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@568a6bb7
2020-11-26 12:21:54.344 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2020-11-26 12:21:54.347 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /error at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.347 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /error at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.348 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@442b46a2: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@442b46a2: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@364492: Username: test; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: F21871A713E04DDC161BC4072F553A68; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.348 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /error at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.348 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /error at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.348 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /error at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.348 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher        : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/logout'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.348 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /error at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.348 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher        : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/login'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.348 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /error at position 7 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.348 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /error at position 8 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.348 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /error at position 9 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.348 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
2020-11-26 12:21:54.348 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /error at position 10 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.348 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /error at position 11 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.349 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@442b46a2: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@364492: Username: test; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: F21871A713E04DDC161BC4072F553A68; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.349 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /error at position 12 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.349 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /error at position 13 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.349 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /error at position 14 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2020-11-26 12:21:54.349 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /error; Attributes: [authenticated]
2020-11-26 12:21:54.349 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@442b46a2: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@364492: Username: test; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: F21871A713E04DDC161BC4072F553A68; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
2020-11-26 12:21:54.349 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased               : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@5adc6cf1, returned: 1
2020-11-26 12:21:54.349 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2020-11-26 12:21:54.349 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2020-11-26 12:21:54.350 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : /error reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2020-11-26 12:21:54.350 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={masked}
2020-11-26 12:21:54.355 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2020-11-26 12:21:54.358 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.template.provider.cache' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String
2020-11-26 12:21:54.362 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.template.provider.cache' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String
2020-11-26 12:21:54.367 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2020-11-26 12:21:54.369 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2020-11-26 12:21:54.370 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 403
2020-11-26 12:21:54.371 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2020-11-26 12:21:54.371 DEBUG 16540 --- [nio-8070-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: You actually did (you should add `permitAll()` after the login, but apparently that works. You should add an `@EnableWebSecurity` so that the default security rules do backoff. Looks like you are missing the CSRF stuff (it is enabled by default) and I suspect due to how you set things up, the automatic addition to the form doesn't work.

Comment: Do I really have to add `@EnableWebSecurity` when using `spring-boot` I thought it would be added by autoconfiguration if `spring-security` is on classpath? At least if works without the annotation, and when using the crsf token. But maybe I should add the annotation anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @M. Deinum I figured out I have to define the thymeleaf form with `th:action` instead of simple action field. Then thymeleaf will automatically inject the `crsf` field:

`<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="25d08979-7785-4131-ac73-a7ce6a16b5ac">`

With this in place, it works as expected.